# Does Rust support comparing struct instances without comparing their fields?

Tags: rust

In JavaScript, one can compare/find objects like this:

```js
let foo = {}
let bar = foo
[foo].includes(bar) // true
```

It's a fast operation, because as far as I know, JavaSscript stores some hidden identifier (memory address?) for every object and just compares them. Rust, on the other hand seems to require implementing the `Eq` trait which compares every single field including those of every underlying data structure. I can imagine that this may be very, very slow, for such a performant language as Rust, so I guess I am missing something. Where am I wrong? Also, can Rust compare objects in a safe manner by their memory address?

To rephrase my question, I want to know if two references point to the same object.

Comment: JS works by comparing references not the objects right? I don't think Rust lets you do that. Is this what you really want to do though? You could have two distinct but equal objects in your array.

Comment: Checking whether two references refer to the same object, and whether two different objects have the same value, are two things which are related but very different.  Comparing addresses is *not* a performance optimization over comparing values, even in JS.

Comment: @hegel5000 I know, to rephrase my question, I want to know if two references point to the same object.

Comment: @BradyDean please see the update